# SQLproducts filter

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-db

I have two tables:

1. sklep_produkty: id | name
2. sklep_atr_prod: id | id_prod | atr | value

[image: atr_prod table]

In url i use ?fq=color('Czerwony'), to get value i use code:

```
$fq = $this->getRequest()->getParam('fq');
$fq = explode(',', $fq);

$myArray = array();
foreach($fq as $param){
    $literal_pattern = "/('[^']*')/";
    $fq = preg_match($literal_pattern, $param, $token);
    $myArray[] = str_replace("'", "", $token[0]);
}
```

Then i get id_prod like this:

```
$filterActionQuery = $db->select()->from('sklep_atr_prod', array('id_prod', 'wartosc'));

foreach($myArray as $parames){
    $filterActionQuery->where('wartosc = ?', $parames); 
}
$filterActionresult = $db->fetchAll($filterActionQuery);
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT `sklep_atr_prod`.`id_prod`,
`sklep_atr_prod`.`wartosc` 
FROM `sklep_atr_prod` 
WHERE (wartosc = 'Czerwony')
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_prod] => 1
            [wartosc] => Czerwony
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_prod] => 3
            [wartosc] => Czerwony
        )

)
```

And this is ok, but when want to use antother filtr "size" i make URL like this: ?fq=color('Czerwony'),size('XL')

SQL Result:

```
SELECT 
`sklep_atr_prod`.`id_prod`,
`sklep_atr_prod`.`wartosc`
FROM `sklep_atr_prod` 
WHERE (wartosc = 'Czerwony') AND (wartosc = 'XL')
```

And this give me empty result. How make SQL query using two parametrs 'Czerwony' and 'XL' to get id_prod = 3.

Comment: ?fq=color('Czerwony')&size('XL')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT sap.id_prod
FROM `sklep_atr_prod` sap
WHERE sap.wartosc IN ('Czerwony', 'XL')
GROUP BY sap.id_prod
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sap.wartosc) = 2;
```

Comment: This "2" means two parametrs? So i must count how many my url have parametrs?

Comment: @Kurczakovsky . . . Yes, the "2" is for the two parameters.